# BodyBuilder.js Query any of array

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, bodybuilder.js

I'm creating an Elastic Search query that queries on two fields using BodyBuilder.js.

One side of the query is string matching to the event type, the other takes in an array of strings and is satisfied if any match.

Query(type) && AnyQuery(arrayOfStrings)

What's the recommended way to both combine queries and how to query for any of an array?

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you could do:

```
bodybuilder()
  .query("term", "event_type", "my_event_type")
  .orQuery("terms", "event_type", [
    "my_event_type1",
    "my_event_type2",
    "my_event_type3"
  ]).build();
```

yielding

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": {
            "term": {
               "event_type": "my_event_type"
            }
         },
         "should": [
            {
               "terms": {
                  "event_type": [
                     "my_event_type1",
                     "my_event_type2",
                     "my_event_type3"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```